# spring data mongodb: compare LocalDateTime query

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the below object

```
@Document(collection = "qr_code")
public class QrCode implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String qrCodeId;

    @Field
    private String codePay;

    private LocalDateTime expiredIn;

}
```

I have this query to check if a `codePay` exists or not

```
boolean existsByCodePay(String codePay);
```

I want another query to check if a `QrCode` is expired or not, based on attribute `expiredIn`, that's to say the `QrCode` expired when `expiredIn < LocalDateTime.now()`

```
@Query(???)
boolean isQrCodeExpired(String codePay);
```

Answer (score 1):

The raw mongodb query can be something like this :

```
{
    "expiredIn":{
        $gt : new Date()
    }
}
```